# How to display only the keys of a javascript object array in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[JSbin for live code example](http://jsbin.com/OGipAVUF/36/edit)

Is it possible to display only the `key` from expression syntax in Angular?  The key being the word being "page".  If so can it be from an array(I know they are the same word)?

**HTML**

```html
<body ng-app="ang6App">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="templatesCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in tempTemp">{{val}}</div>
        <!-- how do I just display the word page? -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```js
angular.module("ang6App")
    .controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {})
    .controller("templatesCtrl", function ($scope) {
    /* $scope.template = Templates; */
    $scope.tempTemp = [{
        'page': {
            'name': 'jordan test page'
        }
    },
    //end of page
    {
        'page': {
            'name': 'jordan test page'
        }
    }];
    //end of templates
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first repeater is just an array so it has no key/value pair

the second repeater loops through all property in item

```
<div ng-repeat="item in tempTemp">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
    {{key}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will mark this correct but is there anyway in angular to call the key directly? {{tempTemp[1].key}}  without repeating?

Comment: then you would have to do something like `$scope.getKeys = function(obj){ return Object.keys(obj) }` and `{{getKeys(item)}}`